# Capybara/Rspec: Filling out Multiple Radio buttons

Tags: rspec, capybara

I figure there is probably a better way to do this then copy-pasting 100 times.

But essentially I have a form page that has a LOT of radio buttons (95 to be exact). That im using `page.find(:xpath)` to `trigger('click')` on.

The Xpath looks a bit like this:

```
page.find(:xpath, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/label').trigger('click')
```

The TR[x] goes up for each row of radio button options, with the TD[x] being which to choose (1-10)

I really am just needing to pick a random number between 1-10 for each TD, for an automation test (just to make sure it works).

Would some sort of for loop accomplish this? Something like: (Im not familiar with ruby, but this is what I pulled up just from a quick google)

```
for i in 1..85
   $h = 1 + rand(10)
   page.find(:xpath, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[i]/td[h]/div/label').trigger('click')
end
```

Would that work?

edit: Here is the HTML for a Row:

```
<tr class="all no-rate complete" data-original="2" change-check="false" the-row="17">
<td class="face">
<td class="face">
<td class="face">
<td class="face">
<div class="radio-inline radio-inline--empty">
<input id="set_stuff_17_rating_3" type="radio" name="set[stuff][17][rating]" value="3" data-control="" data-rating="" filter-class="complete">
<label class="integer opt" for="set_stuff_17_rating_3">Number Rating</label>
</div>
</td>
<td class="face">
<td class="face">
<td class="face">
```

Comment: Do none of the tables or divs have classes or ids, or text to identify them?  Using long xpaths like that really leads to incredibly brittle tests.  If I had to use that xpath I'd do something like `rows = page.all(:xpath, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr', count: 85); rows.each { |row| row.find(:xpath, ".//td[#{rand(10)+1}]/div/label").click }` since I think it makes it clearer what's going on  (not sure whether that should be 85 or 95 you mentioned one in your question and the other in your code

Comment: @TomWalpole They all share the same class name (So that won't work), i've tried using the ID's...but for whatever reason the "choose" selector method for capybara will not work. I had to result to using "find" with the xpath selector.
Im not sure WHY the id wouldn't work, since it seems like it should but the choose selector just doesn't want to work (and my timeout is set to 10 seconds, so it's given plenty of time)

Comment: But doesn't the ancestor table have an id? or anything like that?  I'm guessing choose doesn't work because the radio/checkbox is hidden - which is why you're clicking on the label (FYI Capybara 2.8 when released will click the label automatically if the radio/checkbox is non-visible)- if you can,  just attach the whole html for the page so we can look at it

Comment: Turns out I was actually able to use find_by_id, however for everything i've had to use .trigger('click') (I think the radio buttons themselves sightly overlap the boxes that the radio buttons sit in (from looking at the screenshot). So im going to change everything to that instead (which will make it much less brittle)

Comment: Rather than using `trigger` you should fix the page (make the screen wider, or whatever is necessary) - if you use trigger you are not actually testing that a user could click it

Comment: @TomWalpole What is trigger doing exactly? Unfortunately "fixing" the page is out of my hands at this point (im not a dev). Im using Poltergeist and I can see when taking the screenshots that the radio buttons are slightly off set. So im guessing when it tries to click normally it's clicking the box around it perhaps. 

Unless there is some way to render it wider in poltergeist?

Now that im using id (lets pretend the id is row_0_rating_1) would i still be able to use a loop to click on them?

Comment: Trigger bypasses the checks that the element can actually be clicked and delivers the event directly to the element.  In your driver registration you can change the default window_size for poltergeist - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - it's the :window_size option  -- If you post/link to the html we can tell you the best way to click the buttons you want to, without it I can't really say

Comment: @TomWalpole I edited the question and added the HTML for a Row (Which contains the radio buttons). each "face" class is for a different radio button, but thats with one expanded. With the top class being the class for the row (w/radio buttons) itself

Comment: Does the containing table have an id?

Comment: @TomWalpole  Sadly doesn't look like it "<table class="table table--ratings table--filtering" data-sticky-table-header="" data-filter-table="" style="padding: 0px;">"

Comment: ok -- but it has classes and given its size is probably the only ratings table on the page so I would do     `page.all('table.table--ratings tbody tr', minimum: 85).each { |row| row.all("td label").sample.click }`  which will find the table rows without the huge xpath,  then find all the labels in each row, pick one and click it

Comment: @TomWalpole Thanks, i'll try it out. You seem to know a lot about Capybara, is there any good books for it or did you just pick up this stuff over time w/experience? Also i've never seen .sample? What exactly does that do?

Comment: #sample picks a random member of an Array - http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-sample - The Capybara results from `#all` don't support all methods or Array but `#sample` is one of the ones it does.  I know a lot about Capybara because I'm the current author/maintainer or Capybara :)  No books I know of unfortunately but the code is easy to read, and it's built-in tests make for some decent examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the updated info about the actual structure of the page, something like

```
page.all("table.table--ratings tbody tr", minimum: 85).each do |row|  
  row.all("td label").sample.click
end
```

would do what's being asked without the large brittle XPath expression.

Comment: I think I understand everything in the page.all statement besides tbody tr, what exactly does that mean? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Its a CSS selector, a tr descendant of tbody - it needs to be specified as a descendant of tbody in case you have a thead element with tr children

Comment: Is there any difference in " " and ' ' for css selectors (What you have makes sense now). I thought when defining css in capybara you needed to put ':css' at the beginning?

Comment: Unless you've changed Capybara.default_selector it is set to :css, so if you don't specify anything at the beginning it's assumed to be :css.  No difference between "" and '' here, just what I happened to type.  In ruby strings surrounded with "" get interpolated with '' they don't.

Comment: It actually ended up working, thanks! I wish I could ask a ton of general capybara questions here because I've been using it for awhile but some things I use but I guess im just not 100% sure how it works. 

Is there any where on the Capybara site or you or anyone could just answer some general questions? (even if it's on the chat here) (I've read over the documentation tons of times, there are just some small things Im not sure I understand)

You also talked about built in tests for capybara? Maybe im not familiar with these?

Comment: Theres a mailing list linked off Capybara's README -  http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara and people are sometimes around on https://gitter.im/jnicklas/capybara

Comment: Way better than an XPath and `.sample` makes it cleaner. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over each row :

```ruby
page.all(:xpath, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/table/tbody/tr').each do |el|
  $h = 1 + rand(10)
  el.find(:xpath, './td[#{h}]/div/label').click
end
```

Note that you should refactor your XPath to make it more maintainable.

And with the HTML you provided:

```
page.all(:xpath, "//form//tr[td[@class='face']]").each do |el|
  h = 1 + rand(10)
  el.find(:xpath, "(.//input[@type='radio'])[#{h}]").click
end
```

Comment: How do I refactor the Xpath? i've known Xpath is brittle but not really sure the "proper" way to do it.

Comment: @msmith1114 Show the ancestors html

Comment: @msmith1114, your Xpath should be relative to an element having an id or specifics attributes/classes. How did you get this XPath in the first place? The dev tool in Google Chrome should provide a better one. Note that you could also use a CSS selector.

Comment: I was using firebug (then right click-->copy xpath) on the element